Getting INVALID_SESSION_ID from Salesforce REST API after token refresh
We are getting an INVALID_SESSION_ID when accessing Salesforce via the REST API after a token . We run a refresh token every 30 minutes and have the following settings:

User refresh period is 2 hours
Connected app refresh is 24 hours (have also tried null)
Connected app selected OAuth includes api, refresh_token and offline_access
Connected app is set to ‘Refresh token is valid until revoked’
There are no IP restrictions
IPs are NOT locked to the sessions
We are using https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com

We are getting no errors from the refresh, only when we try and use the token. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Have you checked this?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387018&type=1
https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/272


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
